# Table updates with new content, but Core Data doesnt

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view of all my `entities`, when one is selected, it brings up a `detail view`. In the `detail view` there is an edit `barbuttonitem`. When selected, the code below is run. The table view reloads on viewdidappear, and detects the change in first name, but when I close the simulator and open it again, it shows the previous value. Am I missing something?

```
-(void)doneEditing{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first == %@", _athleteFirst];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    currentAthlete.first = _firstDetailTextField.text;

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem *allAthletesButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"All Athletes" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popACapInYoViewController)];
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(editAthlete)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:allAthletesButton animated:YES];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you *save* the managed object context, so that changes are written to the persistent store and therefore permanent?

Comment: I did not. Could you give me an example? Sorry, i'm new to objective-c and core data.

Comment: Just look up the `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation (or any tutorial): `NSError *error; BOOL success = [context save:&error]; ...`.

Comment: @MartinR: I got it. Thanks! If you make it an answer, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *save* the managed object context, so that changes are written to the persistent store and therefore permanent:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [context save:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"could not save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```